# how to do a subquery or filter in a condition met by a previous query correctly

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Im using **python**, **flask** and **sqlalchemy** have the query below:

```
query = db.session.query(model.Foo1, model.Foo2).join(model.Foo1, model.Foo1.id == model.Foo2.name_id).first()
```

Now let's assume that i want to search for the condition `Foo1.id != 2` but still make sure that i meet the condition of the query above, what would be the best way to achieve that (i am trying to learn how to do `subquery` or `filter in another query` properly)

Thank for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Foo1.id != 2` You don't need a subquery. Filter is enough.

```py
result = db.session.query(model.Foo1, model.Foo2)\
         .join(model.Foo1, model.Foo1.id == model.Foo2.name_id)\
         .filter(model.Foo1.id != 2).all()
```

This will return a list of all rows that have ids not equal to 2